# create an new array of objects from two array of objects in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two array of objects:

```
watches = [
  {
    id: "1",
    label: "Rolex",
    color: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    label: "Omega",
    color: "UUID_OF_BLACK",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    label: "Zenith",
    color: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
  },
];

watch_colors = [
  {
    id: "UUID_OF_BLACK",
    label: "Black",
  },
  {
    id: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
    label: "Silver",
  },
];
```

Now I need to print this in console using vanilla JS

```
Rolex Silver
Omega Black
Zenith Silver
```

I think I need to filter these two arrays by the common value in them both which is UUID and then make a new array and map on it to show data, but I am not sure how to approach in code.

This is what I have done so far

```
function watch() {
  watches.map((watch) => {
    console.log(watch.label);
  });
}

watch();

function color() {
  watch_colors.map((color) => {
    console.log(color.label);
  });
}

color();
```

Comment: So what did you try? [Edit] the question and include your best attempt

Comment: [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in combination with [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop though `watches`, find the matching color from `watch_colors` with `color` value in `watches` array is same as `id` value in `watch_colors` array. i.e, `color.id === watch.color`

```js
const watches = [
  {
    id: "1",
    label: "Rolex",
    color: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    label: "Omega",
    color: "UUID_OF_BLACK",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    label: "Zenith",
    color: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
  },
];

const watch_colors = [
  {
    id: "UUID_OF_BLACK",
    label: "Black",
  },
  {
    id: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
    label: "Silver",
  },
];

watches.forEach((watch) => {
  const color = watch_colors.find((color) => color.id === watch.color);
  if(color) {
    console.log(`${watch.label}, ${color.label}`);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method like the following:

```js
const newWatches = watches.map((val) => {
  const color = watch_colors.find((x) => x.id === val.color);

  return `${val.label} ${color.label}`;
});

console.log(newWatches);
// prints [ 'Rolex Silver', 'Omega Black', 'Zenith Silver' ]
```

Comment: `watches` is already an array, no need to reduce it. Just use the map method and return the string for each iteration. EDIT: a benefit of reduce is when you don't want to add a value if it can't find the color

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more efficient using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to make a dictionary and then loop over `watches` to print the result.

```js
const watches = [
  {
    id: "1",
    label: "Rolex",
    color: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    label: "Omega",
    color: "UUID_OF_BLACK",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    label: "Zenith",
    color: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
  },
];

const watch_colors = [
  {
    id: "UUID_OF_BLACK",
    label: "Black",
  },
  {
    id: "UUID_OF_SILVER",
    label: "Silver",
  },
];

const dict = new Map();
watch_colors.forEach(({ id, label }) => dict.set(id, label));

watches.forEach((o) => console.log(`${o.label} ${dict.get(o.color)}`));
```